# Constructing natural transformations between homology theories on for CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $C$ be the category of finite CW-complexes and

$$ H^1_*,H^2_*: C \rightarrow GR-\mathbb{Z}-MOD$$
two homolgy theoires such that both agree on $0$-dimensional CW-Complexes. Ist it possible to construct a natural transformation from that, such that it is an isomorphism for all finite CW-complexes?

Thank you

Comment: There are several possible definition for "homology theory", it might help to include which one you mean.

Comment: I would guess it is the definition of Eilenberg and Steenrod?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean the definition of Eilenberg and Steenrod.

Comment: If you're have a natural transformation $H_*^1\to H_*^2$ which is an iso on a point, then it is an iso on all CW complexes. You can prove this using Mayer-Vietoris and the 5-lemma. I don't think it's true anymore if you don't have a natural transformation to begin with, @Joe91 .